# Efficient implementation of File Explorer - Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm creating a simple file explorer on Android Studio, and I wonder which one of the following implementations is the best:

**My solution**:
I have an activity called MainActivity that displays my list of files, and each time the user clicks on a directory, it creates a new MainActivity (and the onCreate method gets the new list of files, ...).

**Correction**:
In a correction from a tutorial, I found that when the user clicks on a directory, instead of starting a new activity, the code keeps the current one and changes everything (clear the list and fill it with new files, change the title...).

Is there a solution that is better than the other ? Is it more efficient to keep always the same activity ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a single activity no question about it !

When a user clicks an item you build your data-source based on the newly selected path. Make sure to distinct between files and directories. Then simply call [notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) and thats it !

To query the file system there are two ways:

1. The easy - use Java File.listFiles()
2. The hard - run shell command Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "ls -la" ) and parse response.

There are many open source projects on github for the subject. Example:

[Amaze File Manager](https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's what I thought. To query the file system, I used the Java.File class. Just for my information, are there any cases where one should use the second version (execute shell commands) ?

Comment: Shell commands are slower but return the full list of files including hidden. Also, you can read / write file permissions with shell commands. Some devices like the Huawei mate 9 pro blocks some shell operations. There is a lot of information on the subject just google it  :)